# Add a query param in the URL with polymer iron-location or iron-query-param

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to add a new query param to the existing URL with iron-location/iron-query-params.

I have been trying to set the path property, query property of iron-location and its getting updated but it does not reflect in the browser URl

Similarly I have tried to update the paramString, paramsObject of iron-query-params-component. None of them updates the URL in browser and navigates to the given new URL with update query params.

How do I update the URL which then reflects in browser URL and then navigation happens